# node.js how to get a version of a dependency in run-time particularly for socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a node app using socket io. 
I need to get actual version of socket.io to load client script from cdn.
How can I get this version?

`require('socket.io).version` does not work.

Comment: It seems to work in old versions of socket.io, which one are you using?

Comment: "socket.io": "1.3.4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is require not socket.io lib, but `package.json` file instead.

```
var version = require('socket.io/package').version;
```

Which will give you the lib version. [Found here](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/5ce06d3088660e9d78ad291d9ceb89ba10045d06/test/socket.io.js#L25).